# Data Factory GIT error: Git file and resource name are different

Tags: git, azure-data-factory

Complete newbie here...  I am working in Azure Data Factory and I clicked Validate All and this error comes up:  Arm-template-parameters-definition
Git file and resource name are different.

I have no idea where to look or what this means.  Can anyone explain what this means and/or where to look to resolve it?  I have googled and read, but nothing is clicking right now.  There does not seem to be anything documentation relating to that error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem:  Clicking Validate All in Azure Data Factory produces an error:  Arm-template-parameters-definition Git file and resource name are different.  I do not understand what this error means or how to fix it.  I apologize that I am completely new to this and I don't know where to start looking.  I am looking for education and/or guidance to the error.  Does this help clarify my issue?

Comment: I figured it out on my own.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Now that you've figured it out, you might consider adding a self-answer, so that there's an answer available if someone else has the same issue in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that the trigger file name was not the same as the value recorded in the "name" parameter within the trigger.

e.g. If your trigger is called my_trigger.json, you need to make sure that the trigger reads:

```
{"name": my_trigger ...}
```

and not

```
{"name": something_else ...}
```